# ShadowViewTreeObserver missing in Robolectric 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, robolectric, android-testing

Robolectric 3.0 provided `ShadowViewTreeObserver` class, but it's missing in Robolectric 3.1.

Official upgrade guide (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/3.0-to-3.1-Upgrade-Guide) tells about shadow methods being removed due to duplication of Android API funtionalities, yet `ShadowViewTreeObserver` is not mentioned there.

What happened to this class ? Should Android API methods of `ViewTreeObserver` be used instead of this particular shadow in 3.1 ?

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: I'm not using it right now, I simply learned about it and wanted to try, but found out that it's not included in 3.1. I was interested in firing OnGlobalLayout event to all listeners, but since regular ViewTreeObserver could do the same, I wondered if ShadowViewTreeObserver was simply removed (and upgrade guide failed to mention it), or it's functionality was moved to another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Robolectric 3.1.x there's no more `ShadowViewTreeObserver` class, Check: [Overview](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.1/index.html).

The reason of this change is explained in this `merge` request
[Deleting ShadowViewTreeObserver as it reimplements what the real class does. #2308](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2308/files), which has only one commit named

As you would see the answer for your question would be in commit:
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2308/commits/e10bddd18ebb3df14423d3743e11772e4fd76e49.

What might be interesting for you it has only one commit, which has solution in name as it is called [Deleting ShadowViewTreeObserver. Please use the real class moving forward](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2308/commits/e10bddd18ebb3df14423d3743e11772e4fd76e49).

> tells about shadow methods being removed due to duplication of Android API funtionalities, yet `ShadowViewTreeObserver` is not mentioned there.

Seems to they forgot to update their docs ;-)

Hope it will help